# Why does this assertion fail?

Tags: c

I want to create lirc command to stop recording. I have 3 files for this:

#### File: record.c

```
...
#include "rec_tech.h"
...
void stop_rec_button_clicked_cb(GtkButton *button, gpointer data)
{
    Recording *recording = data;
    close_status_window();
    recording_stop(recording);
}
...
```

#### File: rec_tech.c

```
...
void recording_stop(Recording *recording)
{
    g_assert(recording);

    GstState state;
    gst_element_get_state(recording->pipeline, &state, NULL, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE);
    if (state != GST_STATE_PLAYING) {
        GST_DEBUG ("pipeline in wrong state: %s", gst_element_state_get_name (state));
    } else {
        gst_element_set_state(recording->pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    }
    gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(recording->pipeline));
    g_free(recording->filename);
    g_free(recording->station);
    g_free(recording);
}   
...
```

#### file rec_tech.h

```
...
#ifndef _REC_TECH_H
#define _REC_TECH_H
#include <gst/gst.h>
....
typedef struct {
    GstElement* pipeline;
    char* filename;
    char* station;
} Recording;

Recording*
recording_start(const char* filename);

void
recording_stop(Recording* recording);
...
```

#### File: lirc.c

```
...
#include <lirc/lirc_client.h>
#include "lirc.h"
#include "rec_tech.h"
#include "record.h"

static void execute_lirc_command (char *cmd)
{
        printf("lirc command: %s\n", cmd);

        if (strcasecmp (cmd, "stop recording") == 0) {
            stop_rec_button_clicked_cb(NULL, data);
        }
...
```

When I try to compile get error in file lirc.c

```
error: 'data' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

UPDATE

If in lirc.c add line Recording *data;

```
...
#include <lirc/lirc_client.h>
#include "lirc.h"
#include "rec_tech.h"
#include "record.h"

Recording *data;    
static void execute_lirc_command (char *cmd)
{
        printf("lirc command: %s\n", cmd);

        if (strcasecmp (cmd, "stop recording") == 0) {
            stop_rec_button_clicked_cb(NULL, data);
        }
...
```

get this run-time error:

```
ERROR:rec_tech.c:recording_stop: assertion failed: (recording)
```

Why?

Comment: From the code above `data` isn't defined in `execute_lirc_command`

Comment: How to define data in execute_lirc_command? Recording *recording = data;

Comment: `g_assert(recording);`  <--- checks if `recording` is null... and you passed in null... so....

Comment: The real question is, why not? You seem to be writing random code that you don't understand and hoping that it works. You try to pass a variable called data that you haven't declared, so of course the compiler gives you an error. The proper response is not to just change data to NULL and hope that magically works, but rather to figure out what that argument is for and provide an appropriate value for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `g_assert()` in `recording_stop()` checks that `recording` is not a null pointer, but the modified call in `exec_lirc_command()` passes a null pointer.  So the assertion fails.

Moral — do not pass null pointers to functions that are not expecting them.